Fetch data in server component from an external API which depends on a variable | nextjs 13
I'm trying to fetch data from an external API in a server component which is considered good practice but in this scenario my GET request depends on a variable called menu_id(inside child.tsx) and will fetch different data depending on the value.
i also use zustand as my state manager but i can't get access to it in server components
parent.tsx(server component):
const getMenuData = async (menu_id: number) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${menu_id}/items/}/items/`);
  return res.json();
};

export default async function DashboardLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) { 
return (
    <div className="flex h-screen flex-col bg-primary">
      <ChildComponent></ChildComponent>
    </div>
  );
}

child.tsx(client component):
 export default function ChildComponent({
  name,
  position,
  places,
}: MyPlacesTabType) {
  const [IsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [currentMenu, setCurrentMenu] = useState("venhan");
  const tab = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = (menu_id: string) => {
    setIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
    setCurrentMenu(menu_id);
    //the GET request in parent.tsx depends on menu_id here
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={tab}
     >
      <section>
        {places.map((place) => (
          <Button
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            {place.name}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

what is the right way of providing menu_id to this server component?

if you are required to use api endpoint in the frontend use it. since it is dependent on the menu id coming from the btn click. if u want to maybe hide the 3rd party api endpoint url u can wrap it in a route handler

@cmgchess using route handlers when my API is external always felt unnecessary. Is there anyway to get access to menu_id in parent.tsx?do i have access to menu_id if i use route handler?

The normal way to handle this for things that don't rely on user interaction is to use a cookie which can then be retrieved on the server. Since yours is attached to a click event, it's unreasonable to make a request to the server, set the cookie, wait for a refresh and then use the cookie to run something on the server.
If you really want to streamline this, look into TRPC and setting up both a server and client side client. With that you can write the method once and just import it from a different location depending on whether you want to run it on the server or the client, otherwise you just have to write the query on the client.
The whole 'run your queries in server components' methodology only holds true if the query is something you're running immediately on render where previous approaches involved just putting it in a useEffect hook after the client component renders. Queries that run literally any time after that need to be pushed down to the client (or a server action).
